# Savon Ruby Soap Client - can't create a soap document correctly

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, savon

I admit I'm new to both SOAP and Savon, but I got it working with another service, but this one is stumping me.

The WSDL is here:
http://stg-wholesale.carsdirect.com/ws/services/Ping?WSDL

The Document when done should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <dealerPing xmlns="http://wholesale.carsdirect.com">
            <request>
                <partner>
                    <pricePlan>integer</pricePlan>
                    <id>integer</id>
                </partner>
                <vehicle>
                    <year>integer</year>
                    <make>string</make>
                    <model>string</model>
                    <trim>string</trim>
                </vehicle>
                <zipcode>integer</zipcode>
            </request>
        </dealerPing>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If anyone can get close to generating a document like this or give me some pointers I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried doing something like :

```
client = Savon::Client.new{|wsdl| wsdl.document = @cp.wsdl}
@response = client.dealer_ping do |soap|
  ...
end
```

But, I got this error : undefined method `dealer_ping' for #

I'm pretty much stuck at this point.  My knowledge of both parts of this equation is lacking.

Thanks.

Comment: have to leave for a meeting, but i'll make sure to answer this later today. the quick answer is: use `client.request` and check the documentation at http://savonrb.com

Comment: I did that.  I'm just having some issues understanding exactly how to get the soap request to look exactly like what I need.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: hey erik. i tried to create a valid request using soapUI, but i'm getting a "Error NCWM.PI.426" system error. don't know if i have to guess a proper partner id or price plan, but the request is not successful. could you generate a valid request so i can answer with a working example?

Comment: I can't give that out, sorry.  But, if you can just get savon to generate the xml correctly that would be a huge step in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the service, so I can't try if it works ... but this should probably work:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.endpoint = "http://stg-wholesale.carsdirect.com/ws/services/Ping"
  wsdl.namespace = "http://wholesale.carsdirect.com"
end

client.request(:dealer_ping) do
  soap.body = {
    :request => {
      :partner => {
        :price_plan => 123,
        :id => 1222
      },
      :vehicle => {
        :year => 2010,
        :make => "Aston Martin",
        :model => "DBS",
        :trim => ""
      },
      :zipcode => 90245
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: will give it a shot thanks a lot.  I just brute forced it for now.